# Как подключиться к бд mysql через cmd?

Tags: python, mysql

Всем добрый день. Возник вопрос с бд MySQL. Прописываю в windows 10 в cmd команду:

```
telnet 78.155.220.225 3306
```

Но выводит:

```
Подключение к 78.155.220.225...Не удалось открыть подключение к этому узлу, на порт 3306: Сбой подключения
```

Подскажите, в чём проблема? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/connecting-to-mysql-from-the-command-line

Comment: эта статья не по теме

Comment: Здрасте приехали. Прям в самую суть

Comment: Вам бы курсы какие-нибудь пройти. вы по каждому чиху задаете здесь вопрос. Вы понимаете, что так вы мало чему научитесь?

Comment: а какие посоветуете курсы?